# Can't view my own profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I visit my own profile, when logged in, I get an error:

[image: Oops!]

I can view it when logged out, and I can view other profiles.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same error!

Comment: cross-site duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348987/opening-my-own-profile-page-causes-a-something-bad-happened-error

Comment: We're investigating it.

Comment: @rene of course I should've checked the übermeta...

Comment: This is part of the big-reset. We all start at 1-rep and go from there.

Comment: Solved. Just reload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying my [answer from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348989/164200):

> We pushed a change out that was behind a feature flag. Unfortunately, we missed a page that needed to check for that setting...the profile page.
>
> We've rolled back the build in the meantime, while we fix the issue.
>
> Thanks for the report.